# I have some troubles about Delphi-RTTI (Abstract class, Sealed class etc)

Tags: delphi, rtti

I am trying to develop simple toolsapi plugin for class browsing. I can find all vcl objects and i can show its implementatiton(code definition) inside memo using RTTI.

But, i have some troubles;

***- How can i determine if class is abstract or not.

 - How can i determine if class is sealed or not.

 - How can i find nested classes inside a one class with its visibility.***

I am using Delphi XE5 with RTTI (TRttiContext).

I am using foolowing defines inside my projects source.

```
{$STRONGLINKTYPES ON}
{$RTTI EXPLICIT METHODS([vcPrivate, vcProtected, vcPublic, vcPublished]) PROPERTIES([vcPrivate, vcProtected, vcPublic, vcPublished]) FIELDS([vcPrivate, vcProtected, vcPublic, vcPublished])}
```

Thanks

Comment: It is difficult to know how RTTI comes into this. Tools API plugins usually operate on the code in the editor window. And I don't see how you'd get RTTI for that. This feels like an XY question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Thanks for your interest David.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first two things cannot be retrieved using RTTI (just as you cannot retrieve if a method is overload or override).

To retrieve if a type is nested you can parse its name because a nested type always includes the name of the outer type. But you again have no information about the visibility of the nested type because the RTTI does not know about the nesting.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I am really sorry to hear that. RTTI knows about much more thing but does not know about somethings that before i mentioned. Strange ! I have to determine so i think i will open source file and parse it :(

Comment: There is a reason for this though. RTTI is for Run-time only, available in the application to get info about compiled and registered classes. Those classes you are browsing are nothing yet, but a bunch of sources. They may not even compile or be instantiated.

Comment: That is not a reason. .NET reflection for example has `Type.IsSealed` or `Type.IsAbstract`. If he loads the RTL packages he can read the RTTI just fine. It might not be the best way for an IDE plugin but still.